# How can I change type of input file in html?

Tags: html, file, file-io

I have this html code

```
<input type="file" id="path" name="selectpath"/>
```

but when I click this input it's available only to select file not folders when I click on any folder just open it and not get this path or directory it must select any file (image,text file etc), but I need to select folders only to get directory for any place on client machine 
How can I do it.

Comment: It would help if we knew why you need a directory on the client machine.

Comment: to generate some folders and files in selected directory

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do this without something running on the client, unless you ask the user to save the files manually. Imagine if any site you visited could dump files on your computer.

Comment: aha thanks I do this cause I develop php tool to create and generate some code.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not explicitly through HTML. You need some Java applet or Flash movie to do it. One way I do it is by using a custom PHP script that takes in a zip or tar file and decompresses it on the back end then dumps it.